# How the Apache Cassandra process is named on the Windows?

Tags: windows, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to run Apache Cassandra on the Windows 10, some installation tool place when I ran cassandra.bat for the first time but repeated call to it returns port used errors. So, I suspect that I have already started accidently Cassandra process. How this process is named - for I can check its status in Task Manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Apache Cassandra uses the java runtime, it should show up as `Java(TM) Platform SE Binary`, but the name may vary based on what java installation you are using.

I'll admit that's a bit vague.  I'd recommend using [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to get more details about running programs.

After installing that, locate processes named `java.exe` and hover over them to see the command line arguments.  The huge listing of configuration flags and jar files makes Cassandra a dead give away:

[image: processexplorer]